# To look for words in a dictionary based on random input letters, will this code perform effeciently?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to coding. I tried to build a simple code that can take a subset of alphabet letters and return back a valid words from a text based dictionary.

In the code below, I ask the user to input a number of characters (e.g. abcdef) then the program will make words out of these letters.

Now my question is this the best method to do it in term of performance, code length and the blocks sequence? If not, can you suggest a better way to do?

```
#Read the dictionary

fh = open('C:\\english-dict2.txt')
dict = []
while True:
    line = fh.readline()
    dict.append(line.strip())
    if not line:
        break
fh.close()

#Input letters

letters = input("Please enter your letters: ")
letters_list=[]
for l in letters:
    letters_list.append(l)
mini = 2 #default value
maks = len(letters_list)
mini = input("Minimum length of the word (default is 2): ")

if mini == "":
    mini = 2 #default value
mini = int(mini)

#Here I create a new dictionary based on the number of letters input or less than.

newdic=[]

for words1 in dict:
    if len(words1) <= maks and len(words1)>= mini:
        newdic.append(words1)

for words2 in newdic:
    ok = 1

    for i in words2:
        if i in letters_list:
            ok = ok * 1
        else:
            ok = ok * 0

    if ok == 1:
        print(words2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lists are inefficient for lookups. You should use a dict of sets instead to index every word with each letter in the word, so that you can simply use set intersection to find the words that contain all of the given letters:

```
from functools import reduce
d = {}
with open('C:\\english-dict2.txt') as f:
    for l in f:
        w = l.strip()
        for c in set(w):
            d.setdefault(c, set()).add(w)
letters = input("Please enter your letters: ")
print(reduce(lambda a, b: a & d[b], letters[1:], d[letters[0]]))
```

For example, given a dictionary of the following words:

```
apple
book
cat
dog
elephant
```

The index dictionary `d` would become:

`{'p': {'elephant', 'apple'}, 'a': {'cat', 'elephant', 'apple'}, 'l': {'elephant', 'apple'}, 'e': {'elephant', 'apple'}, 'k': {'book'}, 'b': {'book'}, 'o': {'book', 'dog'}, 'c': {'cat'}, 't': {'cat', 'elephant'}, 'd': {'dog'}, 'g': {'dog'}, 'h': {'elephant'}, 'n': {'elephant'}}`

Here's a sample input/output of the above code, where both the words `apple` and `elephant` are found to contain both of the letters `a` and `e`:

```
Please enter your letters: ae
{'apple', 'elephant'}
```

From here you can easily filter the resulting set based on a given minimum number of letters if you want.

Comment: Wow, I'm impressed by this neat solution! First time heard about lambda. Time to go back to study and practice more. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

*modification 1:* You do not need to loop over letters in `letters`, just

`letters_list=list(letters)`

is enough to make list of letters.

*modification2:* You can make sure any `mini` can be handled using:

```
try:
    mini = int(mini)
except:
    mini = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

For your dictionary, you don't need to iterate through using `readline()`, just do:

```
with open(path) as fh:
    dict = readlines()
```

This will also safely close your file, even if there's an error. If you want to do lookups for words, I'd use a `set` rather than a `list`, as the lookups in `sets` are O(1), whereas lookups in `list` are not, they are O(n).

```
d_set = set(dict)
```

This way if you want to create all combinations of letters, you can look them up like so:

```
import itertools

letters = input("Input your letters, please ")


def check_for_match(combos):
    for combo in combos:
        if combo in d_set:
            yield combo

i = len(letters)

my_list = []

while i:
    combos = itertools.permutations(words, i)
    results = list(check_for_match(combos))
    my_list = [*my_list, *results]
    i-=1
```

This will give you all of the permutations of `letters`, check if they are in your dictionary, and build `my_list` if they are. I think that's what you are looking for